# Why multiple calls of System.out.println prints values in single line

Tags: java, stack-overflow, println

It is just a funny question. Not a real code for production.
I do not want to fix it. I just want to understand this strange behavior.
I have the code that should print "1" in each line. Actually, it is false. I get the strange result like "11111111" in one line.

```
class Scratch
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    method();
  }

  static void method()
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println(1);
      method();
    }
    catch ( StackOverflowError e )
    {
      method();
    }
  }
}
```

Output could be the following:

```
1
11111
1
11111
1
1
1
1
1
11111111
1
11111
```

Comment: You are calling your method recursively and when it errors on an overflow you still call it recursively. Why are you not looping to get the result

Comment: Because your code is broken. You continue to print after an overflow.

Comment: Unlimited recursion + ignored exception == weird

Comment: Please, read the question. I do NOT need a fix. I know that method is incorrect. I just want to understand this strange behavior.

Comment: Well as NovaBomb states, it's probably your output trying to make sense of printing even after stack limits have been reached.

Comment: Probably platform and implementation dependant. `PrintStream` (`System.out`) uses an internal buffer and prints that to the console. Seems like that the *writes* to the buffer occur faster than it can be flushed, thus you get some accumulations of `1111` in a single line. (I have no way to confirm this)

Comment: @Lino  Agree, but do you have any ideas where are missed extra line breaks?

Comment: @Paul print and newline are two different operations in `PrintStream`, `println` just combines them both, I guess that the newline is just very slow to apply, so multiple prints accumulate beforehand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While, as @khelwood said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165707/why-multiple-calls-of-system-out-println-prints-values-in-single-line/55166343#comment97071030_55165707), you shouldn’t have any specific expectations to a program that ignores repeated `StackOverflowError`s. About anything may go wrong.

However, an attempt at a not too unlikely explanation: `System.out.println(1)` consists of printing `1` and the platform-specific new-line sequence — on Windows again consisting of printing `\r` and `\n`. There is nothing stopping the stack overflow from happening between the two or when trying to print the newline after the `1` has been successfully printed. In these cases the next `1` (if successful) will be printed on the same line.

Your output seems to show about 30 `1` and about 12 (full) newlines. So apparently the scenario I sketched has happened a little more than half of the times. *If* this is the correct explanation, which we don’t know.

Comment: *fun fact*: the longer the program runs the more `1`s are printed on a single line, seems that java can't really recover that fast

Answer (score 0):

Curiously tried to work on your code, feeling Daredevilish today..

If you add a `System.out.println(2);` in `catch` you can see that the result now shows that the 1 are being printed in single lines, its the ones from catch and the ones triggering the error which ignore the cursor move from `println`

```
static void method() {
    try {
        System.out.println(1);
        method();
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        System.out.println(2);
        method();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1
1
122
122
1
122
122
1
1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Test {

 static int count = 0; //counter

 public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    method();
  }

  static void method()
  {
    try
    {
        if (count < 10) //Stop code after 10 runs
        {
            System.out.println(1);
            count++; //increments count
            method();
        }
    }
    catch ( StackOverflowError e )
    {
      method();
    }
  }
}
```

Your problem is you can not do recursion without a if or limiting factor. In the code above, I use a count to prevent the coding from printing infinity

Remember any time recursion is used it must have a condition to tell it when to stop

EDIT: As to your printing on multiple lines. It's most likely due to the computer printing infinitely fast enough that it overlaps in places